# Always return false when comparing an object that uses parameter

Tags: java, servlets, set

I don't know why it always return false when comparing to an Account that uses the parameter. It only return true if the Account is hard coded.

```
public class Account
{
    public Account(String username, String password, String lastname, String firstname){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }


    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof Account)
        {
            Account p = (Account)obj;
            if ( getUsername().equals(p.getUsername()) 
              && getPassword() == p.getPassword() )
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**My Servlet**

```
Set<Account> acc = new HashSet<Account>();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        acc.add(new Account("test1", "pass123", "Boom", "Bang"));
            acc.add(new Account("test2", "pass123", "Beam", "Beng"));
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String username = "";
        String password = "";


    if(request.getParameter("Username") != null){
        username = request.getParameter("Username");
    }
    if(request.getParameter("Password") != null){
        password = request.getParameter("Password");
    }

    Account act1 = new Account(username, password, "", "","");
            System.out.print(username+password); // test if the username and password change based on the parameter
            /*
            Works only on hard code
            Account act1 = new Account("test1", "pass123", "", "","");
            */

        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<head><link href='layoutit/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>"
                + "<link href='layoutit/css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>");
        out.print("<title></title>");
        out.print("</head>");
        out.print("<body");
        if(acc.contains(act1)){ // the condition that always return false if not hardcode
                out.print("<h3>Click <a href='displayuser.html'>here</a> to continue.</h3>");
        }
    else
        out.print("<h1>Invalid user account entered.Click <a href='index.html'>here</a> to login.</h1>");
        out.print("</body>");
        out.print("</hmtl>");
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you use .equals instead of == for comparing passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.equals` instead of `==` when comparing the passwords.

(copied from my comment on the question)

Answer (score 0):

Password is also string but you are comparing it using `==`, Use `.equals`. Use it as follows, from below:

```
      if ( getUsername().equals(p.getUsername()) 
          && getPassword() == p.getPassword() )
```

To

```
   if ( getUsername().equals(p.getUsername()) 
          && getPassword().equals(p.getPassword()) )
```

Further when you are using `instanceof` operator, separate null check is not required.

SO, you can write this line

`if (obj != null && obj instanceof Account)`

as

`if (obj instanceof Account)`